# How to apply a termination condition while extracting encrypted message?

Tags: java, cryptography, extract, steganography

First I want to encrypt a message with a key using AES cipher.
Then hide each byte of the encrypted message inside random pixel and that too by replacing one random component of the pixel completely (either red or green or blue).

I use secureRandom to generate same pixels of image and IV for AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding by giving a seed. Let us say no pixel is generated twice to store the byte.

Now I want to extract it.
While extracting, I will generate the same pixels using the secureRandom and with same seed.

What should be the termination condition so that I stop at the last hidden byte's pixel?
In the embedding part, the length of the encrypted message is the termination.
How can we apply a termination condition for the extraction if possible?

Or else is there any way to embed in such a way that we can extract later from those random pixels?

Comment: What was the "termination condition" when you were encrypting the file?

Comment: @hfontanez for encryption it is message length and for embedding it is encrypted message length.

Comment: Why don't you post your code for decrypting and allow us to figure out what is wrong with it? If you haven't written any code, I can assure you not many will be inclined to help you. In today's StackOverflow, people are more aggressive at closing "bad questions." You need to post minimal, reproducible code.

Comment: @hfontanez Ok. But is encryption and decryption code necessary? Because I need for extraction. I think embedding code would be useful.

Comment: I would post both just to make sure. And, it will not hurt if you attach a test file. If you post both, maybe you don't need to attach a test file since anyone should be able to do a "round trip" with any image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just evaluate the length of the ciphertext and store it in the target structure too, but on a fixed location. On decryption phase, read this size information as counter for the number of bytes to retrieve. As an alternative solution you can rely on the fact that a ciphertext is written in multiple blocks of fixed length (which depends on used algorithm and keysize). You can with trail and error try to read and decipher block by block until you got a valid deciphered text or you're out of data.

EDIT:

It's a simple calculation:

Let's say your ciphertext is 1024 bytes long and you use an int for the length information than you need at least 1024 + 4 bytes to store the information.
And let's say you hide your ciphertext in 12345 pixel and you store in the first 4 pixel the length info followed by 1024 pixels with  ciphertext. If you want to retriev ciphertext you first read in the four bytes to get the length and next *length* bytes to get the ciphertext. In the given example you read 1028 bytes/pixel, the remaining 11317 pixel / bytes are not of interest.

It's realy that simple, isn't it?

Comment: But if the length of the ciphertext is more than one byte and suppose if we store the length before the ciphertext, it will be greater than 1 byte. Even for that we need to generate multiple pixels and store. Again we need termination condition for that.

Comment: Thanks I had the same idea but, I was not sure of storing length. Thanks for reminding that converting an integer to byte array has length always 4. I was not even thinking about it. So, now I can read length from first 4 random pixels.